# Dúvida em Laços Python

Tags: python

Galera to quebrando a cabeça aqui faz um tempo, e e um pequeno detalhe, como que eu faço pra exibir os valores abaixo da média?, eu ja coloquei o for pra percorrer a lista mas nao printa. E tambem o valor negativo esta sendo contabilizado na soma.

```
import copy
tempos = []
soma = 0
qtd = 0
while True:
valores = int(input('Valores: '))
tempos.append(valores)
lista2 = copy.copy(tempos)
soma += valores
qtd+=1
media = soma/qtd
if valores < 0:
    break
print(f'MEDIA: {media}')
for c in range(tempos):
   if tempos < media:
     print(f'{tempos:}')
```

mesmo se vc que leu não souber oq é, mas tem uma ideia, comenta ai

Comment: `print(f'tempo abaixo da media:{c}')` é isso?

Comment: na hora de editar sem querer removi a variavel, mesmo colocando a variavel do C deu o erro: 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Answer (score 0):

Você comentou: [...] tambem o valor negativo esta sendo contabilizado na soma.

Isso aconteceu pois logo que você obtém o valor do usuário, você fez o seguinte:

```
valores = int(input('Valores: '))
tempos.append(valores)
```

Neste caso o correto é primeiro você avaliar a entrada do usuário e só depois adicioná-lo.

```
valores = int(input('Valores: '))

if valores < 0:
  break

tempos.append(valores)
```

Você também comentou: eu ja coloquei o for pra percorrer a lista mas nao printa

Desculpe mas não entendi o motivo de você precisar percorrer tudo de novo a cada entrada do usuário:

```
for c in range(tempos):
  if tempos < media:
    print(f'{tempos:}')
```

Mas antes de te passar uma sugestão para isso, quero te informar que tempos é uma variável do tipo list. Neste caso se você quer percorrer os itens basta você usar:

```
for c in tempos:
```

Eu tenho uma sugestão que deve atender ao que você precisa e ficará mais simples:

```
tempos = []

while True:
  valor = int(input('Valor: '))

  if valor < 0:
    break

  tempos.append(valor)
  media = sum(tempos) / len(tempos)

  print(f'MEDIA: {media}')

  if valor < media:
    print(f'O valor {valor} está abaixo da média: {media}')
```

Observe que usei sum para que o Python some os valores armazenados e len para contar quantos itens eu tenho na lista.

Eu coloquei dessa forma mais com o intuito de te ensinar que existem funções no Python que podem te ajudar nessas operações matemáticas.

Espero que eu tenha te ajudado.

Comment: Ahh entendi, valeu pela ajuda, seu algoritimo apesar de estar diferente ajudou uito na minha logica pra desenvolver aqui